# Limit requests per minute with Nginx

Tags: nginx

So I have an Nginx configuration where I would like to limit the incoming requests to an x amount per minute.

The application is behind a load balancer in AWS so I need to be sure to apply the limit to the actual client's IP instead of the load balancers.

So far I have something like this

```
http {
    real_ip_header X-Forwarded-For;
    set_real_ip_from subnet_a/24;
    set_real_ip_from subnet_b/24;
    set_real_ip_from 127.0.0.1;
    real_ip_recursive on;

    limit_req_zone $binary_remote_addr zone=reqlimit:20m rate=200r/m;
    limit_req_status 429;

    server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        limit_req zone=reqlimit burst=20 nodelay;

        ...
    }
}
```

I can see my actual IP in the `access.log` file but the request limit doesn't work as expected.

I would expect the first 200 requests to pass and the rest to get blocked but instead it looks like its a mix of 200 and 429 but I never get to get only 200s.

The result of curling the domain 50 times looks like this

```
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 429 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200 
HTTP/2 200
```

Any idea why this might happen?